# how do I chop up a row of numbers into columns with Perl

Tags: perl, m

I am trying to convert data that is currently being processed by hand into an easier format but I am not a programmer so i really could use some help. Our tab delimited .txt datafile looks as following:

```
Date                :       
Time                :            
Sample name         :       
Temperature         :       
                    :  
-4000     4.882813E-03    4.882813E-03   
-3000     4.882813E-03    4.882813E-03   
-2000     0   0  
-1000    -.1367188    .1367188   
0    -3.554688    3.457031   
1000     -3.632813    3.491211   
2000     -3.657227    3.496094   
3000     -3.686523    3.491211   
4000     -3.710938    3.496094   
5000     -3.735352    3.496094   
6000     -3.754883    3.491211   
7000     -3.774414    3.496094   
8000     -3.793945    3.496094
```

the text and all data until column A reaches 0 is of no importance and should be removed. once column A reaches 0 the script should start scanning column C and once column C changes by say 5% it should cut or copy the next 100 datapoints of column B and put it in colum D, upon the next change the data matching with those points should be placed in column E etc till the end of the file is reached.

with easier numbers:

```
0   1   2
1000    1   2
2000    1   2
3000    1   2
4000    1   2
5000    1   2
6000    1   2
7000    1   2
8000    0   3
9000    0   3
10000   0   3
11000   0   3
12000   0   3
```

should be transformed into:

```
0000    1   2   0
1000    1   2   0
2000    1   2   0
3000    1   2   0
4000    1   2   0
5000    1   2
6000    1   2
7000    1   2
```

I'm a bit at a loss since i know no programming languages except a little bit of perl from years ago, can someone give me some hint on how to do this because right now I can read my text file and display the data in the terminal window of Padre but I have trouble manipulating the data

thank you in advance for any tips tricks and help, other non programming solutions are welcome too because right now me and my colleague are looking at doing this kind of manipulation by hand on ten thousands of these changes

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the Perl code you've already written.  Even if the code doesn't do what you want. We cannot help you if we don't know what you're doing.

Comment: This sounds less like a programming assistance request, and more like you want to hire a programmer. There are a number of 'write some code to my spec' sites out there that might be well suited to this sort of problem.

Comment: It is very odd to add the Perl tag to a question that doesn't contain any Perl code at all. Why have you added the M tag?

Answer (score 1):

#### how do I chop up a row of numbers into columns with Perl

Using the [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) operator

```perl
my $row = '0    -3.554688    3.457031   ';
my @row = split ' ', $row;
say for @row;
```

#### output

```
0
-3.554688
3.457031
```

Comment: I added Perl because that is the only language I know a little bit about. But we found someone from inside our building that has experience with programming and he is going to help us, maybe that is easier :)

thank you for the feedback